# sequence with first difference and second constant ratio in first difference

Tags: sequences-and-series

how to find the $n$th element of sequence where the change between two consecutive element is first geometric sequence  and then the change between two consecutive elements of geometric sequence is constant ratio. what i mean by this is,look at the sequence $1,4,10,22,46, \dots$ it's having first difference like $3,6,12,24, \dots$
(i.e. when we add $1$ to $3$, we get $4$ add $4$ to $6$, we get $10$ and so on) but the difference is geometric sequence with constant ratio $2$ (i.e. $3*2=6$, $6*2=12$ and so on). I hope it clarifies the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the nth number of this sequence:

$4, 10, 22, 46,. . .$;

We have:

$2^2=4$

$2^3+2=10$

$2^4+2^2+2=22$

$2^5+2^3+2^2+2=46$

$2^6+2^4+2^3+2^2+2=94$

.

.

.

Then, letting $n+1=m$ the nth number of sequence is:

$2^m+2^{m-2}+2^{m-3}+2^{m-4}+ . . .+2$

I showed the 6th number is $94$, for another example the 9th number is:

$(m=9+1=10)$

$N_{10}=2^{10}+2^8+2^7+2^6+2^5+2^4+2^3+2^2+2=1534$

Let's check this:

The difference between 4th and 5th number due to your comment must be $2\times 24=48$ so the 5th number must be $94$;

6th: $94+2\times 48=190$

7th: $190+2\times 96=382$

8th: $382+2\times 192=766$

9th: $766+2\times 384=1534 $

Now:

$2+2^2+2^3+ . . . +2^{m-2}=\frac{2^{(m-2)+1}-1}{2-1}-1=2^{m-1}-2$

So:

$N_n=2^m+2^{m-1}-2=2^{n+1}+2^n-2$

The condition holds for any n in N; the general formula is:

$N_n=a^{n+1}+\frac{a^n-a}{a-1}$

For example for $a=3$ we have:

$N_n=3^{n+1}+\frac{3^n-1}{3-1}-1=3^{n+1}+\frac{3^n-3}{2}$

The sequence is:

$9, 30, 93, 282, . . .$

And the differences are:

$21, 63, 189, . . .$

$63=3\times 21$ and $189=3\times 63$ and so on.